# Converting ASP.NET Web Forms application into Desktop Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web-applications, desktop-application

How To convert ASP.NET web forms Application into Desktop Application : \
The target of the conversion is to keep the HTML Interface  with JQuery scripts , ... etc
So is there any available tool that can do this and if not 
are there steps to follow to make good & fast conversion ?

Comment: Not going to happen. Unless you bundle webkit into an application

Comment: webkit is the HTML rendering engine that comes with Safari and Chrome. It's open source. It's basically involves bundling a browser into your application

Comment: Any available examples for any asp.net application ?

Comment: If your clients will always be running on Windows, then you can put a WebBrowser control onto your Windows Form. This is basically Internet Explorer made part of your application (though you'll have a lot of control over it). You _still_ need your ASP.NET application to run on a server somewhere.

Comment: @xsan3x god no. Why would you use HTML and Webkit to render your application instead of WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Because of time  , the application took like 2 months to get finished , but something happened & we need it to be desktop ...

Comment: @xsari3x web applications and desktop applications have radically different architecture. Write it again.

Comment: I think I will use a web borwser integrated in the desktop with http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/ after searching ....

Comment: There could be one more option to make your ASP.NET web forms running on desktop. What do you think of implementing Silverlight Out-Of-Browser feature for web application..??  I think it will be easy instead of convertion web form to desktop applications.....

Answer (score 4):

Converting an Asp.net application to a Winform application is not easy and almost not possible to convert automatically in a nice/maintainable. Web applications and WinForms are inherently different, and should be designed differently. Using a tool to convert then cannot be recommended.

Probably you will have to move all the common business logic functionalities to a class library and reuse them while designing the UI logics from the scratch.

Comment: The main problem is the UI Logic , after all the jquery , HTML , css .... etc I used i need to keep them