# Upload a .net application online?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I'm about to do a project on financial data visualization. Nothing advanced really, just some user input manipulated and visualized as an output with some charts and numbers. The thing is though, that even though the plan is to have it as a `.NET` desktop application to begin with an idea is to later transform it into a web based application. And since I've got no experience with that whatsoever my question is simply: Can one write a desktop application in `C# .NET` and later "upload" or "convert" it into a web based interface without too much work?

I've heard of `ASP.NET` that seems to be a pretty well used framework for web applications, but I cannot find anything about converting a desktop application into `ASP.NET` application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean convert a .NET desktop application into an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: Did you try MyEntireApplication.ConvertTo(ApplicationType.Web, FriesWithThat = true) ? :-)

Comment: Seriously though, it's not possible. The closest thing I can think of is a WPF app that can run in a browser (XBAP) but you need to research to see the implications, one of which is it requires an ActiveX control on the client side.

Comment: XBAP/Silverlight are pretty much your options.

Answer (score 2):

IF you divide your application into parts as you should - e.g. business logic, data access layer etc (into different dlls preferably), then all you need to do is just create a new UI, which isn't as bad as creating the app from scratch...

There is obviously a confusion in definitions. You (and it seems some of the guys that posted their answers here) have probably misunderstood the technology.

You can't compare ASP.NET to C#, because one is a web framework, the other is a programming language. ASP.NET can and does use C# (or VB.NET or other .NET language). ASP.NET can then be divided to MVC and Webforms. If you want to compare it to something, you should compare it to windows frameworks like WPF and Winforms.

That said, if the two apps have the same functionality, the logic and the C# stays basically the same. The only thing that changes is the framework that's used for the UI. That's why I'm talking about dividing the app into subprojects, which you can then reuse as needed.

Comment: So you mean that for example asp.net and C# .net have that similar syntax so one can reuse functions and methods and just create a new GUI?

Comment: @user2950764, don't compare c# and asp.net, they are not different like you probably think. Asp.net is a web framework that uses .NET languages (C#, VB.NET etc). If the functionality of these apps is the same, so is the C# code. Only the UI changes. If you want to compare something, compare asp.net to WPF or winforms.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I got your question, there is no way to convert a .Net Desktop Application to a web application. you will need to re-write it. sorry buddy.

Comment: Too bad! I'll see if I go for web developing right away, but at this point I think I'll go for C# anyway! Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Desktop and Web applications are way different and

Comment: As everyone else has said, you can't go between the two. BUT.. you can host a web application yourself on your own server using IIS, keeping it internal and not facing the Internet. It is usable only by you (or anyone on your network if you allow it), and later you can upload it to one of many hosting providers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.
When you start developing your Application for Desktop (for example with Windows Forms) the differences to a Web Application are too big too automatically convert.

I suggest to make a web Application from the beginning.

MfG Mike

Comment: That's too bad! I thought that since C# is (as far as I know) running on a virtual machine, one could maybe use a virtual machine on the web or something. But this web thing is really just a loose concept at the moment, so I think I'll go for C# anyway. Many thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are service/companies/utilities that do do that, but you don't hear a lot about them, prob because they are not great.  I don't know of other technology families that do that better either.

If the eventual goal is a website, prob just start with the website and forget the desktop.   Slower to develop and more to be aware about to be secure are the other downsides.

the downvotes are prob about the question already being asked.  If you google "stackoverflow: C# desktop to website conversion", here are three posts that are similar, in descending order of informativeness.

[Converting ASP.NET Web Forms application into Desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886658/converting-asp-net-web-forms-application-into-desktop-application)

[Can I convert from C# to asp.Net to host application online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337035/can-i-convert-from-c-sharp-to-asp-net-to-host-application-online)

[How to Convert C# Desktop Application Project to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607370/how-to-convert-c-sharp-desktop-application-project-to-website)

Comment: Well, the goal at this point is mainly to test the concept and the web thing is just an idea on how to take it a step further if it seems to be a success. But I think that the application itself is so simple to implement once the design and so forth is done that it's not really that big of a deal. I apologize if the question was answered before, but I couldn't find anything mostly because I didn't really know what to look for! Thanks for your answer!